# Django Conditional Login Redirect on userType check

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I would like to redirect a user to their profile page when they login.
I have two user types, typeA and typeB.
I have model flags is_typeA and is_typeB to determine the user type.
Each type has its own profile template mysite/accounts/typeA/ and mysite/accounts/typeB/<username.

I am attempting to call a new view on login, called login_success, this is the code:

```
def login_success(request):
"""
Redirects users based on their user_type
"""
if request.user.is_typeA:
    return redirect("typeA")
elif request.user.is_typeB:
    return redirect("typeB")
else:
    return redirect("home")
```

My urls.py is then:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('typeA/<username>/', typeA, name='typeA'),
path('typeB/<username>/', typeB, name='typeB'),
path('login_success/', login_success, name='login_success')]
```

My settings:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login_success'
```

Error I'm getting

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login_success/ Exception Value: Reverse for 'userTypeB' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/userTypeB/(P<username>[^/]+)/$']
```

Comment: Dou need to add the username in the redirect(...)

Comment: I think this is it! Whats the best approach for this?

Comment: Redirect("typeB", username=request.user.username)

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly.  That actually ties a lot of things together for me. Thank you again.